# Error with enum field Hibernate + MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to include an enum field to my entity using @Enumerated, Here is my code :

```html
@Entity
public class Frequency extends AbstractModel {
 
 @Column(nullable = true)
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 protected DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 protected IntervalEnum interval;
}
```

But when building my project, I get the error :

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM' at line 1
```

It's the enum which is responsible of the error, but why ?

```html
public enum IntervalEnum {
 D,
 W,
 M;
}
```

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.16 + MySQL 5.7 + Spring boot 1.5.12

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interval is a reserved keyword for mysql

Use @Column to specify a valid name on

`protected IntervalEnum interval;`

Comment: ok isn't interval a protected mysql keyword ? Can you try to rename it or put the @Column with other name ?

Comment: You are right, Interval is a reserved keyword. I changed the name of the field and it worked.